Is the function $f(n)$ from $\mathbb{N}$ to $\mathbb{Z}$ one-one and onto?
I am analyzing a function $ f: \mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{Z} $, defined as follows:
$$
f(n) =
\begin{cases} 
\frac{n-1}{2}, & \text{if } n \text{ is odd}, \\
-\frac{n}{2}, & \text{if } n \text{ is even}.
\end{cases}
$$
I believe this function is one-to-one because:
1) Odd natural numbers map to distinct non-negative integers.
2) Even natural numbers map to distinct negative integers.
3) There is no overlap between the images of odd and even.

However, I am unsure about whether the function is onto or into. Since the set of natural numbers $ \mathbb{N} $ seems "smaller" than the set of integers $ \mathbb{Z} $, as $ \mathbb{Z} $ contains the full $ \mathbb{N} $, and the full set of negative integers. Intuitively, it feels like $f$ might not be able to cover all integers. Especially because I know that the function is one-one.
Since, the function attempts to cover all the integers, is one-one, but clearly, the domain is smaller than the codomain, would the function be regarded as onto, or into?
If while giving your answer, you can share a link where a situation like this is formally addressed, that would be hugely appreciated.

$f(0)=f(1)$....

@dmtri Unfortunately, there is no standard convention about whether $0$ is included in $\Bbb N$ or not, and the OP didn't clarify that. In this case, since the function is being constructed to be a bijection, my guess is that $0$ is not included, but OP should mention that in the post.

Duplicate question, hence should be closed. This is the most standard bijection between N and Z.

Short answer is that if you use the caveman convention that $\min\Bbb N=1$, then it's bijective. Otherwise it is surjective and not injective.

@SassatelliGiulio +1 for "caveman convention"

@XKH I am not sure if that one is the duplicate because it doesn't prove the bijective property.

Depends on whether you consider $0\in\mathbb N.$

I don't consider $0$ to be in $\mathbb{N}$. And the supposed "similar question" answers my doubt.

@MartinBrandenburg It shows the idea of proving the bijective property, maybe it's enough.
